# C++ Loop through first K elements of unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I have an unordered_map that stores counts of integers. I want to loop through the map, but instead of fetching all the entries, I only wish to get the first K.It is guaranteed that map has more than K entries.

I'm running into issues when I do the following:

```
  unordered_map<int, int> u_map;
  // Logic to populate the map
  
  for(auto it=u_map.begin(); it!=u_map.begin()+2; it++)
  cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<endl;
```

The expression u_map.begin()+2 is causing the issue.

So is it possible to get only the first K entries of a map using for_each loop in C++?

Comment: You can use `std::advance` or `std::next`. A map doesn't provide random access iterators, so that's why what you have it causing an error. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21626211/920069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only wish to get the **first** K

Note from [std::unordered_map documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/begin/)

> an unordered_map object makes no guarantees on which specific element is considered its **first** element.

This essentially means that there is no guarantee that you will iterate over the elements in the inserted order.

For iterating over the elements of the map you can use:

```
int count  = 0;
for (auto& it: u_map) {
    /* some code here like you can keep a count variable that will check if it 
    reaches the number K and then break the loop. But remember that it is 
    **not** guaranteed that the elements you will get will be in inserted order.*/
   
   if(count < K)
   {
    cout<<it.first<<" "<<it.second<<endl;
   }
   else 
   {
      break;
   }
   ++count;
}
```

**Working example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> u_map = {
        {"RED","#FF0000"},
        {"GREEN","#00FF00"},
        {"BLUE","#0000FF"},{"PURPLE","#0F00FF"},{"WHITE","#0000RF"},{"ORANGE","#F000FF"}
    };
   int K = 3; 
   int count  = 0;
   for (auto& it: u_map) 
   {
       if(count < K)
       {
            cout<<it.first<<" "<<it.second<<endl;
       }
       else 
       {
            break;
        }
        ++count;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++20, then [`views::take`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view) would be a choice.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::unordered_map<int, int> u_map;
  for (auto [key, value] : u_map | std::views::take(2))
    std::cout << key << " " << value << "\n";
}
```

Alternative for pre-C++20, using [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> u_map;
auto end = std::next(u_map.begin(), 2);
for (auto it = u_map.begin(); it != end; ++it)
  std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << "\n";
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use C++20 in the project. However thanks a lot for this solution. Wasn't aware of this.